# NodeJS Multer validate fields before upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express, multer

I'm trying to validation my form before i upload images but i getting empty string on my middleware

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});

router.post('/upload', formsValidation, upload.fields([{

  name: 'images',
  maxCount: 20

}, {

  name: 'imageMain',
  maxCount: 1

}]), function(req, res, next) {
  code...

});
```

heres my middleware:

```
function formsValidation (req, res, next) {

  console.log(req.body) //getting empty array here
  return next();
}
```

i know that i can use fileFilter from multer but some times i dont have any images to upload just string to store and validate, i have tried to parse the req.body from multipart/form-data to string then validate and use next() but i get a range error, any ideia how can i solve this?

Comment: req.file ? 4 more to go

Comment: getting undefined from req.file

Answer (score 1):

This is from Multer's [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer):

> Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends
>   on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

That's mean you have to call `formsValidation` just after multer midlleware, to make sure that all posted data have been fully populated

```
router.post('/upload', upload.fields([{

    name: 'images',
    maxCount: 20

}, {

    name: 'imageMain',
    maxCount: 1

}]), formsValidation, function(req, res, next) {
    code...
});
```

Comment: i did in this way but why i validate a form if the image are alrealy update ? maybe delete all image if form goes wrong or i have saw that have onParsedEnd from multer can i do a form validation there?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I think you want to validate `req.body` and it's empty because of the order of your form inputs, if your file input located at top of the form, `req.body` will be empty. try to put your file input at the end of the form in order to catch other inputs in `req.body` object, also make sure to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware before all of that

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Before the call to Multer middleware (`upload.fields(...)`), the request body hasn't even begun to be parsed yet. The Express `req` object you receive in your `formValidation()` middleware is only an instance of [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage), which itself is an instance of a [`stream.Readable`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streamreadable), whose data hasn't been consumed yet. Only once you call the Multer `upload.fields(...)` middleware (or any other middleware provided by Multer), the `req` stream is piped through `Busboy` (the `multipart/form-data` request parser used by Multer), and the fields & files get parsed and populated **(in order of their appearance)** to `req.body`.

**Solution**

Unfortunately, Multer doesn't provide functionality to handle field events, only files. You can validate the fields that were populated in `req.body` before a file was received (as outlined in [this Github issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/150#issuecomment-121349692)), however:

1. That strongly ties your validation implementation with Multer's API;
2. As you noted yourself, there can be cases where you send/received no files, but still want to validate fields.
3. Validation will reduntantly run each time a file is encountered – if you have 3 files, validation on `req.body` will run three times. This shouldn't have a huge effect on performance, but still, it's not very elegant.

I'm not aware of any other workaround using Multer. That's why I've written [`pechkin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pechkin) to solve this exact problem.

- `pechkin.parseFormData()` returns a `Promise` that resolves when all fields are parsed, **and** if the first file is encountered (or the request ended).
- The promise contains a populated `fields` object, and a `files` `AsyncIterator/AsyncIterable`.
- No need to provide storage engines, file handlers, event listeners, etc.

This means you can perform validation on the `fields` object, and only then have to mess with files – the files won't be parsed, processed, written to memory, saved anywhere, etc., until you decide to do so.

```js
// ESM
import { parseFormData } from 'pechkin';

// CommonJS
const { parseFormData } = require('pechkin');

// ...

app.post(
  '/upload',
  pechkinFileUpload(/* ...optional configs */),
  formsValidation,
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Process files and/or fields (`req.files`) ...
  }
);

function formsValidation (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body) // No longer empty! Populated with all fields (see note)
  return next();
}

// Just a utility function to follow Express' middleware style
function pechkinFileUpload (/* ...optional configs */) {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { fields, files } = await parseFormData(req, /* ...optional configs */);

      req.body = fields;
      req.files = files;

      return next();
    } catch (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
  }
}
```