# Express Multer validate fields before upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have been seen this : [NodeJS Multer validate fields before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173677/nodejs-multer-validate-fields-before-upload) but is not work. i tried for make validate field before upload in a days and the result is not working. is it because mutler can't do this?

Iam using MERN : MongoDB,React,Express,Node

[image]

i want validate this data in Form-data : dataMurid before uploading the image. 
is there another way to overcome this? Maybe using other library? and please give me exampale code.

**Route**

```
// @route buat edit/create murid baru
router.post('/datasiswa/create',(req, res,next) => {
    upload(req,res,(err)=>{

        let request = JSON.parse(req.body.newMurid);
        // upload(req.body.data.data, res, (err) => {
        //     console.log(req.body.data.data);
        // });
        const { errors, isValid } = validateMuridInput(request);

        // Check validation
        if (!isValid) {
            return res.status(400).json(errors);
        }
        const muridFields = {};
        if (request.tempatLahir) muridFields.tempatLahir = request.tempatLahir;
        if (request.jenisKelamin) muridFields.jenisKelamin = request.jenisKelamin;
        if (request.nis) muridFields.nis = request.nis;
        if (request.nama) muridFields.nama = request.nama;
        if (request.tanggalLahir) muridFields.tanggalLahir = request.tanggalLahir;
        if (request.namaAyah) muridFields.namaAyah = request.namaAyah;
        if (request.namaIbu) muridFields.namaIbu = request.namaIbu;
        if (request.noTelepon) muridFields.noTelepon = request.noTelepon;
        if (request.hpSiswa) muridFields.hpSiswa = request.hpSiswa;
        if (request.hpIbu) muridFields.hpIbu = request.hpIbu;
        if (request.hpAyah) muridFields.hpAyah = request.hpAyah;
        if (request.alamat) muridFields.alamat = request.alamat;

        Murid.findOne({ nis: request.nis })
            .then((murid) => {
                if (murid) {
                    errors.nis = 'NIS ini sudah terdaftar';
                    return res.status(400).json(errors);
                } else {

                    const newMurid = new Murid(muridFields);

                    newMurid.save()
                        .then((murid) => {
                            res.json(murid);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });


                }
            })
    });


});
```

**Upload func**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');

// UPLOAD IMAGE

// Set Storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './public/uploads/',
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
    }
});

// Init upload 
let upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    limits:{fileSize:1000000}, //file size dalam bit
}).fields([{ name: 'fotoDisplay' }, { name: 'newMurid' }]);
```

Answer (score -1):

With multer, in your req.file, you have all the fields about the file.

```
var multer = require('multer')
    var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
    import fs from 'fs-extra'

    router.post('/register', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) => {
        return fs.readFile(req.file.path)
                .then(content => {
                    // The content of the file
                })
    }
```

req.file has the mimetype and so much more that you can check

Comment: i want to validate other data not file data, i want validate this data : dataMurid

Comment: @FarisDewantoro did u get any soloution?

Comment: try use this -> express-fileupload @MaxySpark