# How to prevent saving images when body has error. Express and Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using multer to upload image and i send it from req.file and the image has some information in the req.body like name,tag and... . but the problem is that when body has error(for example a validation error like "name is required") the image is still saved.

How can i prevent saving image when body has error?

Here is my upload middleware

```
const multer=require('multer')
const storage= multer.diskStorage({
    
    destination: function(req,res,cb){
        cb(null,'./images/')
    },
    filename: function(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,new Date(). toISOString().replace(/:/g,'-')+ file.originalname)
    }
})
const filefilter=(req,file,cb)=>{
    if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        cb(null, true);
      } else {
        cb(null, false);
        
    }
}
const upload=multer({
    storage:storage,
    limits:{
    fileSize:1024*1024*5
    },
    fileFilter:filefilter
});

module.exports=upload;
```

and my post router

```
router.post('/', [Auth, Admin], upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.file)
        return res.status(400).send("you didn't upload image (jpeg OR png)")
    const { error } = validate(Object.assign({}, req.body, { image: req.file.path }));
    if (error)
        return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let singer= await Singer.findOne({ singername: req.body.singername});
    if (singer) return res.status(400).send('Singer already added');

    singer= new Singer
        ({
            singername: req.body.singername,
            tag: req.body.tag,
            image: (process.env.BASE_URL || config.get('BASE_URL')) + req.file.path,

        })
    await singer.save();
    return res.status(200).send(singer);

});
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173677/nodejs-multer-validate-fields-before-upload

Comment: use a middleware where you validate the fields and put it before upload.single('image') in your route