# Multer with Body validations

Tags: node.js, express, multer

**I have this router**
this.router.put("/", upload.array("pdf", 10), this.updateApplicant);

**I want to validate the body first before uploading the files**
this.router.put("/",validateBody ,upload.array("pdf", 10), this.updateApplicant);

***But that does not work, because I cannot access the req.body. multer is the one doing the parsing***

**Is there any way to validate the body before going to the multer middleware or uploading the files**

I tried doing this "this.router.put("/",validateBody ,upload.array("pdf", 10), this.updateApplicant);"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS Multer validate fields before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173677/nodejs-multer-validate-fields-before-upload)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I somehow found a way! solved already thanks!